# One of My .H Files Suddenly Causes Problems

Tags: ios, file

One of my .h files looks funny all of a sudden (the one colored in red in the screenshot):

[image]

I tried to delete the file and re-enter it; it works while the project remains open, but once I close the project and re-open it it becomes 'weird' again.

Anyone has any idea what may cause this and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not reading it in your project folder. You probably deleted it manually from the folder, and Xcode keeps finding the reference because in its eyes the file should be there.

This also happens when you are using source control and you manually delete a file from the repository. Usually creating the file again and right clicking it in Xcode and delete fix the issue.